# How to avoid character encoding exceptions that occur when importing CSV data in to MS SQL server?

Tags: feeds, 10

When I try to import CSV data into my feed, I get errors like this:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An
> error occurred translating string for input param 3 to UCS-2: No
> mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code
> page. : INSERT INTO [watchdog] ([uid], [type], [message], [variables],
> [severity], [link], [location], [referer], [hostname], [timestamp])
> OUTPUT (Inserted.wid) VALUES (:db_insert0, :db_insert1, :db_insert2,
> :db_insert3, :db_insert4, :db_insert5, :db_insert6, :db_insert7,
> :db_insert8, :db_insert9); Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] =>
> feeds [2] => SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating string for
> input param 6 to UCS-2: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in
> the target multi-byte code page. : INSERT INTO [node__field_body]
> ([entity_id], [revision_id], [bundle], [delta], [langcode],
> [field_body_value], [field_body_format]) OUTPUT (1) VALUES
> (:db_insert0, :db_insert1, :db_insert2, :db_insert3, :db_insert4,
> :db_insert5, :db_insert6); Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 195 [1] =>
> 250 [2] => resource [3] => 0 [4] => en [5] => State departments of
> education may volunteer to pre-populate local surveys with data. Local
> school district can affirm to have this data pre-populated or
> �opt-out� and complete the CRDC on their own. If they choose to
> �opt-out� and then change their mind at a later date, this tip sheet
> shows school districts how to add SEA representatives back into the
> CRDC system. [6] => plain_text ) )

How should I act on this?  The error message seems to indicate that the feeds module wants the character encoding to be UCS-2 -- is that correct? Or are some other characters encodings also acceptable?

Is the issue best addressed in my settings for the feed, for the Feeds module generally, or within the source document?

---

The database is MSSQL. Though I would rather the project used a LAMP environment, that is not an option for this project.

Comment: That is the database driver sending the error message, not Feeds. What is the actual character set of the watchdog table on that site? UCS-2 seems totally wrong for Drupal 10. It should be utf8mb4.

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: That’s a collation not a character set. But it’s not looking good on your end. You need to convert to utf8mb4 character set and an appropriate collation.

Comment: You could do some custom patching to convert encodings on-the-fly but the root cause is a weird unsupported character set in that database.

Comment: If this is MS SQL Server then you should read https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv/issues/2168191#comment-8641749, and yes, you may have to patch Feeds.

Comment: Good news is that I don't have this issue when I find & replace curly quotes with straight quotes prior to the import.  Bad news is that there are multiple other issues.  I will probably use my own script for the import in this case, and I'll give Feeds another try the next time I work on a project that doesn't use MS SQL.